# Rapoport-Zink proof of purity of monodromy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, langlands-conjectures

Hi,

Does anyone know if the article

"Über die lokale Zetafunktion von Shimuravarietäten. Monodromiefiltration und verschwindene Zyklen in ungleicher Charakteristik", INvent. Math, 68 (1980)

by Rapoport and Zink has been translated or if the contents of the article
(for example, the cases of the proof of the purity of the monodromy filtration) can be
found anywhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the papers of Tetsushi Ito or Ehud de Shalit would be useful; see Section 5 [of this paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0301/0301201v3.pdf) or this [paper of Scholl](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ajs1005/preprints/weil.pdf) (with references to Deligne's original conjecture and proof (in equal characteristic case).

Also, recent progress has been reported by Scholze; see this  [MO Q/A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65729/what-are-perfectoid-spaces/66563#66563) especially the last sentence.